# Join two tables with group

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I need help with a query joining two tables for a hostel (dorm) database:

Rooms - room id, category, rent, no of beds, etc

Hosteler - hosteler id, name, room id, etc

I need to generate a result set giving all the rooms, total no of beds and occupied no. of beds and free no of beds, etc

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT r.R_ID , r.R_Beds, count(h.h_id), (r.r_beds-count(h.h_id)) ,
if((r.r_beds-count(h.h_id))>0, 'Available', 'Full' ) , r.r_rent
FROM T_Rooms r LEFT OUTER JOIN t_hostelers h
ON r.r_id = h.h_roomno
WHERE h.h_status= 'active'
GROUP BY h.h_roomno
```

But I am getting only rows from rooms table which have a value in hostelers table. I need to show other rooms with no occupancy also.

Please help me find out my oversight or mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
SELECT r.R_ID , r.R_Beds, count(h.h_id), (r.r_beds-count(h.h_id)) ,
if((r.r_beds-count(h.h_id))>0, 'Available', 'Full' ) , r.r_rent
FROM T_Rooms r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_hostelers h
  ON r.r_id = h.h_roomno
     AND h.h_status= 'active'
GROUP BY h.h_roomno
```

Option 2

```
SELECT r.R_ID , r.R_Beds, count(h.h_id), (r.r_beds-count(h.h_id)) ,
if((r.r_beds-count(h.h_id))>0, 'Available', 'Full' ) , r.r_rent
FROM T_Rooms r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_hostelers h
  ON r.r_id = h.h_roomno
WHERE
     (h.h_status= 'active' or H.H_Status is null)
GROUP BY h.h_roomno
```

The problem is your where clause is excluding records from t_rooms because there is no record in t_hostelers.  To correct you need to apply the filter on the join so it only applies to the t_hostelers OR include NULL results in a where clause.

Comment: Actually the rows are not getting eliminated because of the WHERE clause. It is because there will not (or need not) be rows in the T_Hosteler table for all the rows in T_Rooms table.

Comment: Then can you provide some sample data and expected results as I do not understand the problem.

Comment: I must disagree on your comment: Say I have T_ROOM 1 with NO record in T_Hosteler.  When this is left joined 1 will still be in the result set.  However when the DBEngine applies your where clause, record 1 will be REMOVED because T_Hostler.H_status is equal to NULL not 'active' as a result any room without a record in t_Hostlers will be excluded (by the where clause).  This negates the the benefit of the left join.